# Users Restriction ( prevent users executing files )

Tags: permissions, users

I want to create a user in such a way that he/she cannot execute any file

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10

#### UPDATE

I tried `chmod 700 /bin/sh + /bin/chmod` as root

in this way is there any way or any possibility that users can execute files ?

Can anyone provide me some step-by-step instructions please?

Comment: 2 answers has been tested > non worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the umask property of the user to 113.

The user file-creation mode mask (umask) is use to determine the file permission for newly created files. It can be used to control the default file permission for new files. It is a four-digit octal number. A umask can be set or expressed using Octal values

Calculate umask for any user as follows :

The octal umasks are calculated via the bitwise AND of the unary complement of the argument using bitwise NOT. The octal notations are as follows:

Octal value : Permission 
0 : read, write and execute
1 : read and write
2 : read and execute
3 : read only
4 : write and execute
5 : write only
6 : execute only
7 : no permissions

if you want to restrict your newly created user from executing any file, set his umask to 113( it means he can only read and write the file, his group can only read and write the file while anybody else can only read the file)

The default umask of any user in linux is 002 and for root user is 022.

You can default umask for any user like this:
1) open   /etc/profile 
2) modify the following line "umask 022" according to the default permissions you want to give to your user.

Check the man page of umask for further reference

```
man umask
```

Comment: Users will retain right to chmod their files, so they'll be able to change permissions to *executable*. I don't think it is an option here.

Comment: This is the permissions of chmod command 

ls -al /bin/chmod
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42588  /bin/chmod

you can restrict other users from executing it. by changing permissions of chmod command :)

Comment: u can do sh script .. not working

Comment: chmod 700 /bin/sh + /bin/chmod as root

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing something like that will be to mount separate filesystem in noexec as user(s) homedir:

Create a file image (512M) with ext4 filesystem on it:

`~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/homedir_image seek=512 count=512 bs=1M`

`~# mkfs.ext4 /var/homedir_image`

Then add it to /etc/fstab with noexec option:

`/var/homedir_image /home/user   ext4 noexec,loop 0       2`

Then mount that image in future user's dir:

`~# mkdir /home/user && mount /home/user`

And create required user:

`~# adduser --home /home/user user`

User will be able to create files with x permission, but will not be able to execute **anything** located on his homedir filesystem.

Comment: The part with file image is optional, of course, as You just can use separate disk partition.

Comment: user1@ubuntu:~$ mkdir 123
mkdir: cannot create directory `123': Permission denied
user1@ubuntu:~$ pwd
/home/user1

Comment: i did the same thing ..the thing is that user1 cannot even create a folder

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention that You should change user's folder ownership, as it is likely owned by root by now.

`chown -R user1:user1 /home/user1`

Comment: chown user1 ...it worked but still user can execute file

Comment: chmod 700 /bin/sh + /bin/chmod as root < thats a little bit working